# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: how fixed it?

Tags: java, android

Hello fried my app is app live on playstore it work many devices perfect recently i open my developer console and check crash reporting from developer console i received this error from developer console from this device Tecno Pouvoir 3 Air (TECNO-LC6), Android 9
 i know its not very common device i want to know why its give me this exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at ly.b (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290002@20290002.249178941.249178941:2)
  at lx.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290002@20290002.249178941.249178941:1)
  at lz.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290002@20290002.249178941.249178941:29)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.aq.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290002@20290002.249178941.249178941:10)
  at lc.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290002@20290002.249178941.249178941:8)
  at lc.run (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290002@20290002.249178941.249178941:2)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at ad.loadClass (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@18456111@18.4.56 (110304-262845133):4)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Comment: Do you have `multidexenabled` in your `build.gradle`?

Comment: @ReazMurshed no